# Why my terminal starts without command prompt?

Tags: command-line

Anytime I open my terminal there is no command prompt - it starts blank. I need to either wait like for like half a minute, or type something.. then it actually shows the command prompt and starts reacting.

Is there any way to make it work immediately after open?

Comment: Probably some initialization takes time. Please share your `~/bashrc` or `~/zshrc` (depends on the shell you use).
Also, please check here what is the purpose of `rc` files: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: @Milso - it's `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`

Comment: Do you use zsh or bash ? What's the output of `echo $SHELL` ?

Comment: my  output of echo $SHELL is /bin/bash